# How are elements stored in elements in the xml ElementTree in Python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am processing an xml file for a project and am able to extract the required values using the documentation. Looking into the root element of the ElementTree in the debugger, I am however not able to understand where the relations to the other elements are stored. From reading some more online I understand it to be a network of nodes, but there does not seem to be any reference to the next node(s) in the object. Could someone elaborate how this works?

*Example*:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("data.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

print("Set a break point on this line")
```

Inspecting the root object only shows the following attributes:

- tail {NoneType} None
- tag {str} 'data'
- text {str} '\n\n'
- attrib {dict: 0} {}

I would expect there to be either a list of child elements or at least a reference to another node.

N.B. I know how to access and modify the data that I need, I am wondering how the information is structured within the object.

Comment: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html): Iterate to see the children, e.g., `print(list(root))` or `for child in root: print(child)`.

Comment: Think of an `Element` as a list-like container, where the child elements are the items in the list.

Comment: If possible, a C implementation is used where the children's list isn't available from Python as an attribute. See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_elementtree.c#L216